# When to use OR , AND in MYSQL for advanced search query result

Tags: mysql, variables

I am trying to build an advance search option for our website. I am having trouble getting this to work? Basically the only thing that needs to be constant is the '**review_live = 1**' , the rest is only if the user searches for it. Why isn't this working correctly, maybe I am not using OR, AND correctly in longer queries...

```
    WHERE 
    review_live = 1 AND
    city LIKE '%$location%' OR 
    region LIKE '%$region%' OR 
    date BETWEEN '$beginDate' AND '$endDate' OR
    name LIKE '%$name2%' OR
    type LIKE '%$type1%' OR 
    type_2 LIKE '%$type2%' 
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first suggestion:

```
WHERE 
review_live = 1 AND 
(
  city LIKE '%$location%' OR
  region LIKE '%$region%' OR 
  ( date BETWEEN '$beginDate' AND '$endDate' ) OR
  name LIKE '%$name2%' OR
  type LIKE '%$type1%' OR
  type_2 LIKE '%$type2%' 
)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

### EDIT:

I am guessing you replace all your `like` strings with `'%'` if the user doesn't want to filter that criteria. Then try this:

```
WHERE 
review_live = 1 AND 
city LIKE '%$location%' AND 
region LIKE '%$region%' AND 
date BETWEEN '$beginDate' AND '$endDate' AND
name LIKE '%$name2%' AND
type LIKE '%$type1%' AND
type_2 LIKE '%$type2%'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: no error, it is just not filtering the way I want it too. When I try ?type1=2 for example, it returns all records.. ?

Comment: if you leave the like strings with `%` then you have to replace the `OR` with `AND`. See edit.

Comment: Great, the Second one worked great!! That is it!! Great answer and visually, I can see how to structure these queries next time!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to have review_live = 1 AND all the other stuff. All the other stuff is city or region, or ...

WHERE 
    review_live = 1 AND **(...)**
    ORDER BY date DESC